# textarea text erases when using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have this function which uses `innerHTML` to insert `html` into a `div`:

```
function displayInputIntro() {
                var submitbutton = document.getElementById('submitbutton')
                var intro = document.getElementById('Intro')
                var introNewSection = document.getElementById('intro-row')
                var uniqueID = ""
                var chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
                var length = 7
                for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) uniqueID += chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
                uniqueID = uniqueID
                introNewSection.innerHTML += '<div class="col-lg-5 mb-lg-0 mb-4" id=' + uniqueID + '><div class="card z-index-2"> <div class="card-body p-3" style="margin-top: -20px;"> <h6 class="ms-2 mt-4 mb-0">Intro <a href="#" onclick="javascript:deleteInput(' + uniqueID + ')" style="text-align: right; float: right; margin-right: 12px;"><i class="fa fa-times" style="color: gray;"></i></a></h6> <p class="text-sm ms-2">Section 1</p> <div class="container border-radius-lg"> <div class="row"> <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="intro" placeholder="Enter your current Intro" id="textvalue" style="height: 100px;" required></textarea> </div> </div> </div> </div></div>'
                submitbutton.style.display = ''
             }
```

and then my `html`:

```
<div class="row mt-4" id="intro-row"></div>
```

however, as you can see in the `introNewSection.innerHTML`, I have a `<textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="intro" placeholder="Enter your current Intro" id="textvalue" style="height: 100px;" required></textarea>`

the problem is, this function `displayInputIntro()` can be triggered multiple times. Every time its triggered, and there's any text inside the textarea, it just clears it and I don't know why. how can I fix this?

Comment: add some uniqueid for textArea too and check with any where you were overriding it

Comment: By using `innerHTML` you rerender *all* the content of the `#intro-row` element, including any filled in `<textarea>` fields.

Comment: In this code, you textArea isn't closing properly. Update it properly

Comment: @Suresh why isn't it closed properly, what do you mean?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier ohh okay. How would I go about changing that?

Comment: After formatting your html i see your html as  <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="intro" placeholder="Enter your current Intro" id="textvalue" style="height: 100px;" required>< textarea>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you need to close the HTML tags properly,   is not closing properly , i see  is not having closing tag while assigning html to innerHTML, Second thing whenever you are using innerHTML it will override the html content.
If you want to inject the html then use insertAdjacentHTML tag and execute as below

```
introNewSection.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', 'additional HTML code');
```

Note: You should find out why the function is triggering multiple times.

Comment: `afterend` should be `beforeend`. Otherwise you would render the new HTML *after* the *ending* tag of `introNewSection`.

Comment: it is as per his requirement, i just gave reference code for insertAdjacentHTML

Comment: thank you so much! It worked! and @EmielZuurbier , changing it to beforeend did the trick. thanks